# Deploy Django CMS on IIS Server

Tags: python, iis, window, cgi, django-cms

After learning from this [tutorial](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html) now I can run Django CMS on my laptop using virual envronment.

[image]

[image]

But I want to deploy this CMS to IIS server. 
I also installed

```
pip install wfastcgi
```

But when I try to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in IIS CGI Setting, I find that I still don't have .settings file yet.
[image]

Regarding to setting, below are only files which i have so far.

[image]

So, my question is how can I do to deploy Django CMS on IIS Server ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Roll back all changes related to wfastcgi. 2) Use HttpPlatformHandler, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ 3) Give up Python virtual environment as it does not work well with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the tutorial. I found the problem you mentioned. Actually, the settings.py file in your screenshot is the ".settings" file you are missing.

And you want to know how to deploy Django CMS on IIS Server.  You can refer to [this tutorial](https://blog.nonstopio.com/deploy-django-application-on-windows-iis-server-93aee2864c41) for the steps. Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Any tutorial with `wfastcgi` is at least not recommended by Microsoft, who deprecated that module, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022#configure-the-fastcgi-handler